# Search results differ for users searching a shared mailbox in Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

Just like the questions states. We are using Outlook Ver 2302

We have a mailbox that holds a ton of information. All the billing info is emailed to this email address. Therefore, users use this mailbox to dig up old invoices etc.

This is mostly used by two users. One can search just fine. They will search and email pops up. They are also new to the company.
The other user has been with the company for decades now, when they search email may or may not show. It does help if the time criteria is adjusted in the search options. However, that is not a viable solution because user may not have any idea how old an email could be.
I am guessing this has something to do with how big their Outlook data file is....or some other setting.

- I have tried rebuilding the index
- I can not delete and create a new profile.
- The mailbox is shared, I cannot remove the access and add it as a secondary account. No one knows the password to account.
- I have deleted the data file.
- They are searching in Current Mailbox
- Search works fine with their inbox

What else can I try?

Comment: I assume as an Administrator you cannot change the password to the account?

Comment: Change the password.   Then, for the problem user, uninstall Office, delete the Outlook Profile.  Restart the computer, install Office, update it.  Make a new Outlook profile and then see if Search works.

Answer (score 1):

For search issues in Shared mailbox, please refer to the below and try to troubleshooting: Shared Mailbox: [Problems with search results](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshooting-outlook-search-issues-2556b11f-f4d8-46be-b0a7-de33a3f4f066#:%7E:text=the%20Control%20Panel-,Shared%20Mailbox%3A%20Problems%20with%20search%20results,-If%20you%27re%20not)

[image]

> The mailbox is shared, I cannot remove the access and add it as a secondary account. No one knows the password to account.

As i know, to add Shared Mailbox as a secondary account, we don't need the passowrd of the shared mailbox. It's suggested that you could try the following steps to add it as a secondary account:

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.